# Unable to login Jenkins-Invalid username or password error

Tags: authentication, jenkins

I am not able to login to Jenkins, the credentials are saved in my system. I did not change the credentials and used to login successfully earlier.
Now I come across this error. how to resolve this?
Got some solutions like changing hash password in config,not sure how to generate the same?

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to the server, go to the jenkins home directory and open the config.xml file. In there you find a tag:

`<useSecurity>true</useSecurity>`

change it to false and you dont have to enter a password.

Comment: Thanks for the response. However the strange thing is I do not have useSecurity tag in my config file.

Comment: That's weird, could you post the first 15 lines of the config file?

Comment: <?xml version='1.1' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<user>
  <version>10</version>
  <id>****</id>
  <fullName>*****</fullName>
  <properties>
    <jenkins.security.ApiTokenProperty>
      <tokenStore>
        <tokenList/>
      </tokenStore>
    </jenkins.security.ApiTokenProperty>
    <com.cloudbees.plugins.credentials.UserCredentialsProvider_-UserCredentialsProperty plugin="credentials@2.3.0">
      <domainCredentialsMap class="hudson.util.CopyOnWriteMap$Hash"/>
    </com.cloudbees.plugins.credentials.UserCredentialsProvider_-UserCredentialsProperty>

Comment: On my windows 10 it's at C:\ProgramData\Jenkins\.jenkins

Answer (score 0):

If you are installing Jenkins as a 'Windows service', Use user name : admin & password : {initial password provided by Jenkins).